# Application hosted on AppHarbor, how can I save uploaded images?

Tags: file, appharbor, paas, filepicker.io

AppHarbor (like Heroku) doesn't allow you to save uploaded files or images. I need to offload this somewhere and I have no idea what services exist for this purpose.

I've looked into FilePicker.io but they display a tacky branding image in their uploader and to remove that branding you have to pay a large sum of money.

Any suggestions on how to approach this problem? What is the modus operandi with applications that need file uploads that are hosted on PaaS?

Comment: Filepicker.io allows you to add your own logo and custom css even on the free plan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We recommend that you use Amazon S3 to store files like this. An AppHarbor user has written a [guide on how to get started with S3 on the support forums](http://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/749-handling-uploading-files).